# OleDbConnection not found while using System.data namespace in code

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, oledb

In my code, I am using OleDbConnection. When I refer to System.Data, it gives me the error that OleDbConnection is not found. But when I refer to System.Data.OleDb namespace then it runs fine.
Why is this error occurring?
I checked for the reference via add reference path for System.Data and it exist.

---

Find the below code for better clearance:

```
using System.Data;

public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  OleDbConnection oledbconn;
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
}
```

In above code, **OleDbConnection oledbconn;**---This line no 4 gives error that

**Type or namespace OleDbConnection cannot be found**

And now consider the following code,

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OleDbConnection oledbconn;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Here the code works fine,

I know that adding OleDb to System.Data will resolve my issue but I want to know why does it gives error in first place even if I have referred to System.Data namespace,

According to my knowing, when I refer to System.Data, it indirectly refer to all his child elements like OleDb, SqlClient and all..isn't it?

Comment: Can you give a screen shot or something so that we can understand the issue?

Comment: your question does not have enough information...Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Data` is the assembly you reference to in your project. It contains *many* namespaces within it, one of which is `System.Data.OleDb`.

If you right-click on the `System.Data` reference > View in Object Browser, you can browse for everything within the assembly. You can see in there that the `OleDbConnection` class is contained within the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace.

If you're unsure about where a class lives, always search in MSDN. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) would immediately tell you that `OleDbConnection` lives in:

> **Namespace:** System.Data.OleDb
>
> **Assembly:** System.Data (in System.Data.dll)

Comment: Please refer to the question that I have edited, I know that System.Data.OleDb exist in System.Data but my question is even System.Data should work...isn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The `using` directive should be followed by a namespace, and namespaces are not nested.  E.g. If you want to use both `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` and `System.IO.File` classes, you can **not** simply use `using System`. You have to specify both `using System.Diagnostics;` and `using System.IO;`.